# Pumping Lemma Contrapositive, why is this proof wrong?

Tags: automata, pumping-lemma

I have this proof trying to show L={0}^* {1}^* is not a regular language, I know that L is regular but I don't know what in this proof is wrong. If y contains a 0 and 1 and is pumped wouldn't that make the any word not be in the proper form like going from 000111 to 0000101111?

Let p≥0
. We construct w=0⌈p/2⌉1⌈p/2⌉
; w
is in L
and |w|≥p
. Let w=xyz
with |xy|<p
and |y|>0
. Assume the middle word y
contains both 0
and 1
. This implies that xy2z
is not a sequence of 0’s followed by a sequence of 1’s, so that xy2z∉L
. Hence L
is not regular

Answer (score 1):

You're not allowed to assume that $y$ contains both 0s and 1s.
Take for example $x = \varepsilon$, $y = 0$ and $z = 0^{\lceil \frac{p}{2} \rceil - 1}1^{\lceil \frac{p}{2} \rceil}$ with $w = xyz$, then for $p \geq 1$

1. $|y| = 1 > 0$
2. $|xy| = 1 \leq p$
3. $xy^nz = 0^{\lceil \frac{p}{2} \rceil + n - 1}1^{\lceil \frac{p}{2} \rceil} \in L$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$

The [Pumping lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages) only requires that at least *one* such factorization of $w$ exists that satisfies 1.-3., not that *all* factorizations of $w$ do.

Comment: Ah ok so we can't assume specific partisans then?

Comment: @user167205 You can't.
The Pumping lemma is an existential statement, so if you want to show a counterexample you must prove that all factorizations don't fit 1.-3. ($\neg \exists \to \forall \neg$)